# Plotting colour gamuts in Mathematica

Tags: colors, wolfram-mathematica

I am currently learning Wolfram Mathematica, I want to manually plot colour points on a CIE chart and manually join them with a boundary line.

I am confused as to how Mathematica converts colour space primaries (p3 in my example) to display on a CIE31 chart.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

I've read about converting xyY to XYZ is this a step that I need to do here? Could anyone advise on this?

Cheers.

Comment: I can get it to work with the following: `data = ColorConvert[Green, "XYZ"]` and `ChromaticityPlot[data, "CIE31"]` - I'd like to plot the P3 primaries

Answer (score 0):

At least your definition of p3 misses a comma, i.e. it should be `0.320}, {0.265` instead of `0.320}{0.265`.